# Start services at system starup

Tags: 18.04, 20.04

Hi I have a question I have 3 application, and I want to start them when system is booting up. So i though I use rc.local file, but there seems to be a problem. It looks like application are started parallel but my applications are depended on each other, that means app1 starts then app2 starts.

My rc.locale:

```
#!/bin/bash

dotnet /srv/DiagAC2/WebApi/MDP.Api.dll &
dotnet /srv/DiagAC2/Hub/CL.Hub.dll &

exit 0
```

Is there a way in Ubuntu to start application in some specific order?

Comment: Drop the ampersand?  That one is detaching them from the script so makes those 2 parallel. Otherwise you will need to learn how to use systemd  That one can start units based on other units that need to be started 1st ;-)

Comment: remove all ampersands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to execute them in parallel you can do this :

```
dotnet /srv/DiagAC2/WebApi/MDP.Api.dll && dotnet /srv/DiagAC2/Hub/CL.Hub.dll
```

If the first one returns successfully ( return code of 0 ) then the second one gets executed.( you can replace the double ampersand `&&` with semicolon `;` to eliminate the `successful return` condition)

And if it doesn't take much time to get executed , you can add that line to your `~/.profile` file in order to execute them every time you log in as your user.(but it may slow down the logging-in process.)

But if it takes so much time , you should consider [creating a systemd service](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-systemd-service-unit-in-linux) for it and you have to add the above command to the `ExecStart` option of your .service file (full path not just `dotnet`)

If there's any better solution , I'm glad to hear.